# Ansible: How to iterate over a role with an array?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to call a role multiple times in a loop like this:

```
vars:
  my_array:
    - foo
    - bar
    - baz 
roles:
  - role: foobar
    with_items: my_array
```

How can we do this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Now supported as of [Ansible 2.3.0](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17966):

```
- name: myrole
  with_items:
    - "aone"
    - "atwo"
  include_role:
    name: myrole
  vars:
    thing: "{{ item }}"
```

Comment: @tomasbedrich can you verify that? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Note that if you use any loops in "myrole", you need to add `loop_control: loop_var: foo` to avoid colliding with inner loops.

Comment: Is there any way to provide a whole dictionary as vars per loop iteration?

Comment: You should rather link to the docs here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html instead of to the ticket which was reported on version 2.3.0, as the the feature was already introduced in **version 2.2.0**

Answer (score 7):

There's [no way to loop over a role](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/B5547FiIhYA/-iJ7Zl7E5ccJ) currently but as mentioned in that Google Group discussion you can pass a list or dict to the role and then loop through that internally.

So instead you could do something like:

```
# loop_role/tasks/main.yml

- name: debug item
  debug: var="{{ item }}"
  with_items: my_array
```

And then use it like this:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    my_array:
      - foo
      - bar
      - baz 
  roles:
    - { role: loop_role, my_array: "{{ my_array }}" }
```

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. Now there is a way, as other answers have mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

You can do so using the include_role module. [See docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html)

According to the docs it was **introduced in Ansible 2.2** already (not in 2.3 as others have stated).

The code would then look like

```yaml
- name: Use role in loop
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: my-role
  vars:
    some_role_variable: '{{ loop_var }}'
  loop:
    - '{{ roleinput1 }}'
    - '{{ roleinput2 }}'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: loop_var
```

Comment: Post example of code. Not just link to external resource

Comment: The link is 404 now

Answer (score 6):

I used something like below on Ansible version 2.8

```
tasks:
  - name: looping role to create multiple filesystem
    include_role:
      name: /opt/ansible/playbook/app_filesystem
    vars:
      vgname: "{{ item.vgname }}"
      lvname: "{{ item.lvname }}"
      lvsize: "{{ item.lvsize }}"
      mountpoint: "{{ item.mountpoint }}"
    loop:
      - { vgname: 'vgapp', lvname: 'lvapp', lvsize: '30g', mountpoint: '/app' }
      - { vgname: 'vgapp', lvname: 'lvappzk', lvsize: '64g', mountpoint: '/app/z' }
      - { vgname: 'vgapp', lvname: 'lvappdatazk', lvsize: '+100%FREE', mountpoint: '/app/data/zookeeper' }

tasks:
  - name: looping role to create multiple filesystem
    include_role:
      name: /opt/ansible/playbook/app_filesystem
    vars:
      vgname: "{{ item.vgname }}"
      lvname: "{{ item.lvname }}"
      lvsize: "{{ item.lvsize }}"
      mountpoint: "{{ item.mountpoint }}"
    loop:
      - { vgname: 'vgapp', lvname: 'lvapp', lvsize: '30g', mountpoint: '/app' }
      - { vgname: 'vgapp', lvname: 'lvappzk', lvsize: '64g', mountpoint: '/app/zookeeper' }
      - { vgname: 'vgapp', lvname: 'lvappdatazk', lvsize: '+100%FREE', mountpoint: '/app/data/zookeeper' }
```

Comment: Did you intend to post one task as an answer or both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample for using include_role looping on my_array:

```
- name: Use role in loop
  include_role:
    name: myrole
  loop: "{{ my_array }}"
```