# Ansible: run role for each member of a list variable?

Tags: ansible

With a variable defined as:

```
ports:
  - 8092
  - 8093
```

I would like to deploy two separate instances of my app on the same server, and configure Apache as a load balancer between the instances. Here's a pseudo-code playbook:

```
- hosts: servers
  roles:
    - app port={{item}}
      with_items: ports
    - configure-apache
```

Seems `with_items` doesn't work in this context.

Whilst it's possible to have two runs of the role, each with hard-coded ports, and then to hard-code the list of ports that the `apache` role uses,  I feel there must be a more elegant solution that uses a single defined list of ports?

Suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible: How to iterate over an role with an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415992/ansible-how-to-iterate-over-an-role-with-an-array)

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, I moved the tasks in `roles/tasks/main.yml` into a new file called `roles/tasks/instance.yml`

Then I modified `roles/tasks/main.yml` to contain:

```
- include: instance.yml
   with_items: "{{ports}}"
   loop_control:
     loop_var: port
```