# How to execute alternating roles in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I need to somehow loop over a list of variables and execute both of the below roles once for each iteration,  on each iteration passing a variable to the role.   For example, given a variable list of 100-101,  I need to execute in the order role1:100, role2:100, role1:101, role2:101.  The variables 100-100 should be passed to the tasks inside the role.

```
---
- hosts: group1
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: role1

- hosts: group2
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: role2
```

I was looking at the below answer as a possible solution but I am not sure how to adapt it to my needs.  Can the above scenario be accomplished in Ansible?

[Ansible: How to iterate over a role with an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415992/ansible-how-to-iterate-over-a-role-with-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the Cartesian product of variables and role names:

```
vars:
  roles_to_include:
    - role1
    - role2
  values_to_pass:
    - 100
    - 101

tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: "{{ item.1 }}"
    vars:
      my_variable: "{{ item.0 }}"
    loop: "{{ values_to_pass | product(roles_to_include) | list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks,  this executes the roles in the required order.  Another requirement is that role1 needs to run on one set of hosts (group1) and role2 on a separate group of hosts (group2).   So far I have been able to get the above working with a single host group,  how can it be adapted to run each role on a separate group of hosts?

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I had asked in the above comment by adding a conditional to the tasks inside each role like this:   when: "'group1' in group_names".