# Calling roles in a loop using dictionaries from an array as vars

Tags: ansible, roles, provisioning, ansible-role

My question is somehow similar to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415992/ansible-how-to-iterate-over-a-role-with-an-array), but that doesn't quite answer it.
In my case I have an array containing multiple `vars:` entries, which I loop over when calling a certain role. The following examples shows the idea:

some_vars_file.yml:

```
redis_config:
  - vars:
      redis_version: 6.0.6
      redis_port: 6379
      redis_bind: 127.0.0.1
      redis_databases: 1
  - vars:
      redis_version: 6.0.6
      redis_port: 6380
      redis_bind: 127.0.0.1
      redis_databases: 1
```

playbook.yml:

```
...

- name: Install and setup redis
  include_role:
    name: davidwittman.redis
  with_dict: "{{ dictionary }}"
  loop: "{{ redis_config }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: dictionary

...
```

As far as I understand, this should just set the dictionary beginning with the vars node on every iteration, but it somehow doesn't. Is there any chance to get something like this to work, or do I really have to redefine all properties at the role call, populating them using `with_items`?

Answer (score 0):

Given the role

```yaml
shell> cat roles/davidwittman_redis/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: dictionary
```

Remove `with_dict`. The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - some_vars_file.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Install and setup redis
      include_role:
        name: davidwittman_redis
      loop: "{{ redis_config }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: dictionary
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************

TASK [Install and setup redis] ********************************

TASK [davidwittman_redis : debug] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  dictionary:
    vars:
      redis_bind: 127.0.0.1
      redis_databases: 1
      redis_port: 6379
      redis_version: 6.0.6

TASK [davidwittman_redis : debug] ******************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  dictionary:
    vars:
      redis_bind: 127.0.0.1
      redis_databases: 1
      redis_port: 6380
      redis_version: 6.0.6
```

---

> Q: *"Might there be an issue related to the variable population on role call?"*

A: Yes. It can. See [Variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). `vars_files` is precedence 14. Any higher precedence will override it. Decide how to structure the data and optionally use `include_vars` (precedence 18). For example

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars: some_vars_file.yml
    - name: Install and setup redis
      include_role:
        name: davidwittman_redis
      loop: "{{ redis_config }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: dictionary
```

Ultimately, command line *--extra-vars* would override all previous settings

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars "@some_vars_file.yml"
```

---

> Q: *"Maybe it is not possible to set the vars section directly via an external dictionary?"*

A: It is possible, of course. The example in this answer clearly proves it.

Comment: While I can confirm, the variables are added, it still seems to ignore them. Might there be an issue related to variable population on role calling?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Just to clarify, I was not referring to variable precendence but to (possible) mismatches when setting the vars section via a loop. Maybe it is not possible to set the vars section directly via an external dictionary? Any variation of notations I tried to run resulted either in the role using its defaults or ansible complaining about misuse of syntax.

Comment: It's not possible to proceed here this way. Open a new question and make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please!

Comment: I might have explained myself a little bad. The overall question I'd like to have answered is still what you already answered to. But even though it looked promising, it did not result in the role using the two different sets of variables. Thats why I brought in those thoughts about what else could cause this issues. I'd still be happy if we are able to come up with a working example for the code I gave in my question.

Comment: Sure. This is also my intention. Open a new question and make it `mcve`. I'll not proceed to guess. Read `mcve` properly, 1) make it minimal (e.g. complex Redis structure is not necessary, simple `key: val1` will serve the purpose; create new empty role for testing and make minimal changes; post it) 2) make it complete (if there is an error message, post it) 3) make it verifiable (post all details (minimal! but all) to reproduce your problem).

Comment: I will do so as soon as I can and place a cross reference between the questions.