# Playbook cannot find "{{ item }}" from loop variable inside role

Tags: ansible

The goal is to remove one or more snapshots to specified hosts. First and second role is working.
The issue is the third role.

If name of snapshot is defined, use second role.

If no name of snapshot is defined use the third role with the names from variable "days" and loop it trough the list. The role will then remove snapshots with those names, if they exist.

My playbook:

```
- name: Managing Snapshot(s)
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  become: false
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    -  confirm
    - { role: remove-snapshot, snapshot_state: "{{ sss | default('absent') }}", snapshot_name: "{{ ssn }}", when: ssn is defined }
    - { role: remove-snapshot, snapshot_state: "{{ sss | default('absent') }}", snapshot_name: "{{ item }}", loop: "{{ days }}", when: ssn is undefined }
```

Command i run for third role:

```
ansible-playbook snapshot-remove.yml --ask-vault-pass -e target=all -e sss=absent
```

Task role is running:

```
- name: remove Snapshot
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  vmware_guest_snapshot:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
    folder: "/vm"
    name: "{{ vm_name | default(inventory_hostname) }}"
    validate_certs: false
    state: "{{ snapshot_state | default('absent') }}"
    snapshot_name: "{{ snapshot_name | default('Using_Default_Text') }}"
    description: "{{ lookup('env','USER') }} {{ lookup('pipe', 'date +\"%F\"') }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Variable "days" that is inside role/remove-snapshot/vars/main.yml:

```
vars:
  days:
    - lookup('pipe', 'date +\"%F\"')
    - lookup('pipe', 'date -d "-1 days" +\"%F\"')
    - lookup('pipe', 'date -d "-2 days" +\"%F\"')
    - lookup('pipe', 'date -d "-3 days" +\"%F\"')
```

Error i receive:

```
fatal: [HOST-MGM]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ item }}: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/user/linux-patching/ansible/roles/remove-snapshot/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: remove Snapshot\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

I have tried using vars, include_vars and vars_files inside third role and received the same error. Creating a new role might solve the issue but i would prefer not creating one more role.

Comment: Isn't the error clear? `item` is not defined, but you are using in on the third role of your playbook. It is nowhere to be found in the variables you are showing us either, so, most likely, it is indeed not defined.

Comment: Hi. On loop im using "{{ days }}" who then should loop task for each name in the variable. To call the names from the loop to snapshot_name i use "{{ item }}".
Example can be seen here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Comment: Did you realise that there is no loop in what you are showing here?

Comment: In my code "my playbook" you can see the condition loop on my third role.
Is it becuse my loop condition is inside the role and should be outside?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415992/ansible-how-to-iterate-over-a-role-with-an-array

Comment: You are describing a role to be played for which you define a variable named `loop` and which value is `"{{ days }}"` <= this not a loop, just a (pretty bad) variable definition.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to solve my problem in a different way.

Decided to add date to description of snapshot for when snapshot was created and the name of snapshot will be the default name "OS_Patching".

With this i will be able to remove snapshots created from another playbook whos purpose it to create snapshot and patch the host.

New code:

```
- name: Managing Snapshot(s)
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  become: false
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    -  confirm
    - {
      role: snapshot,
      snapshot_state: "{{ sss | default('absent') }}",
      snapshot_name: "{{ ssn | default('OS_Patching') }}"
      }
```

Command:

```
ansible-playbook snapshot.yml --ask-vault-pass -e target=<hosts> -e sss=<state> -e ssn=<name>
```

They way i wanted to do was more complicated, this playbook should be easier for managing snapshots.